# I get an [AttributeError: module 'code' has no attribute 'Main'] error, but the attribute is clearly there. Why?

Tags: python, object, module, discord, bots

I'm trying to link a Discord bot to a text-game I made, but when I attempt to call the Class of the game itself, it tells me,

```
AttributeError: module 'code' has no attribute 'Main'
```

Here's my code:

```
# bot.py
import code # Import the code for the actual game

main = code.Main() # Begin the game's processes
```

```
# code.py
class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.otherModule() # This module is used to continue the flow throughout the class
```

I can't see what's wrong with it. When I try to look it up, I'm only told to "just give it a class."

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Are you able to verify that the imported module `code` is the same `code.py` that has the `class Main`?

Comment: How do I verify that? There aren't any other modules with the name `code` in my project files

Comment: Use `print(module_name)` or `print(code)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `code`. The module `code` already exists as a built-in module in Python3.

```
Python 3.10.4
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import code
>>> print(code)
<module 'code' from '/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py'>
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#module-code